# MSP430 I²C Bus: Phase between clock and data

Tags: i2c, msp430

I am currently trying to use the TI MSP430 sample code to send commands from my MSP430FR2512 microcontroller to a [PCA9955B](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9955B.pdf) LED driver.
Unfortunately, I don't receive an acknowledgment from the driver (address is 0x01). It seems like clock and SDA are half a period shifted and not by 1/4 period as shown in a [TI document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva704/slva704.pdf?ts=1671520405028&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F):

[TI I2C Timing Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J8aZ.png)

[Measured I2C Communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHSfl.jpg)

Is this normal?

This is the slightly changed example code I used (essentially only using the init and master write functions):

```c
//******************************************************************************
//   MSP430FR2422 Demo - eUSCI_B0, I2C Master multiple byte TX/RX
//
//   Description: I2C master communicates to I2C slave sending and receiving
//   3 different messages of different length. I2C master will enter LPM0 mode
//   while waiting for the messages to be sent/receiving using I2C interrupt.
//   ACLK = NA, MCLK = SMCLK = DCO 16MHz.
//
//                                     /|\ /|\
//                   MSP430FR2422      4.7k |
//                 -----------------    |  4.7k
//            /|\ |             P1.3|---+---|-- I2C Clock (UCB0SCL)
//             |  |                 |       |
//             ---|RST          P1.2|-------+-- I2C Data (UCB0SDA)
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//
//   Lixin Chen and Xiaodong Li
//   Texas Instruments Inc.
//   Dec 2020
//   Built with CCS V10.1
//******************************************************************************

#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//******************************************************************************
// Pin Config ******************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#define LED_OUT     P1OUT
#define LED_DIR     P1DIR
#define LED0_PIN    BIT0
#define LED1_PIN    BIT1

//******************************************************************************
// Example Commands ************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#define SLAVE_ADDR  0x01

/* CMD_TYPE_X_SLAVE are example commands the master sends to the slave.
 * The slave will send example SlaveTypeX buffers in response.
 *
 * CMD_TYPE_X_MASTER are example commands the master sends to the slave.
 * The slave will initialize itself to receive MasterTypeX example buffers.
 * */

#define CMD_TYPE_0_SLAVE      0
#define CMD_TYPE_1_SLAVE      1
#define CMD_TYPE_2_SLAVE      2

#define CMD_TYPE_2_MASTER      5

#define TYPE_0_LENGTH   1
#define TYPE_1_LENGTH   1
#define TYPE_2_LENGTH   1

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE     20

/* MasterTypeX are example buffers initialized in the master, they will be
 * sent by the master to the slave.
 * SlaveTypeX are example buffers initialized in the slave, they will be
 * sent by the slave to the master.
 * */

uint8_t Message1_Reg = 0x02;
uint8_t Message2_Reg = 0x45;

uint8_t Message1 [TYPE_2_LENGTH] = {0x14}; // LED 1,2 fully on
uint8_t Message2 [TYPE_2_LENGTH] = {0xFF}; // All LEDs full gain
//uint8_t MasterType2 [TYPE_2_LENGTH] = {'F', '4', '1', '9', '2', 'B'};
//uint8_t MasterType1 [TYPE_1_LENGTH] = { 8, 9};
//uint8_t MasterType0 [TYPE_0_LENGTH] = { 11};


uint8_t SlaveType2 [TYPE_2_LENGTH] = {0};
uint8_t SlaveType1 [TYPE_1_LENGTH] = {0};
uint8_t SlaveType0 [TYPE_0_LENGTH] = {0};

//******************************************************************************
// General I2C State Machine ***************************************************
//******************************************************************************

typedef enum I2C_ModeEnum{
    IDLE_MODE,
    NACK_MODE,
    TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    RX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    TX_DATA_MODE,
    RX_DATA_MODE,
    SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE,
    SWITHC_TO_TX_MODE,
    TIMEOUT_MODE
} I2C_Mode;


/* Used to track the state of the software state machine*/
I2C_Mode MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;

/* The Register Address/Command to use*/
uint8_t TransmitRegAddr = 0;

/* ReceiveBuffer: Buffer used to receive data in the ISR
 * RXByteCtr: Number of bytes left to receive
 * ReceiveIndex: The index of the next byte to be received in ReceiveBuffer
 * TransmitBuffer: Buffer used to transmit data in the ISR
 * TXByteCtr: Number of bytes left to transfer
 * TransmitIndex: The index of the next byte to be transmitted in TransmitBuffer
 * */
uint8_t ReceiveBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint8_t RXByteCtr = 0;
uint8_t ReceiveIndex = 0;
uint8_t TransmitBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint8_t TXByteCtr = 0;
uint8_t TransmitIndex = 0;



/* I2C Write and Read Functions */

/* For slave device with dev_addr, writes the data specified in *reg_data
 *
 * dev_addr: The slave device address.
 *           Example: SLAVE_ADDR
 * reg_addr: The register or command to send to the slave.
 *           Example: CMD_TYPE_0_MASTER
 * *reg_data: The buffer to write
 *           Example: MasterType0
 * count: The length of *reg_data
 *           Example: TYPE_0_LENGTH
 *  */
I2C_Mode I2C_Master_WriteReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count);

/* For slave device with dev_addr, read the data specified in slaves reg_addr.
 * The received data is available in ReceiveBuffer
 *
 * dev_addr: The slave device address.
 *           Example: SLAVE_ADDR
 * reg_addr: The register or command to send to the slave.
 *           Example: CMD_TYPE_0_SLAVE
 * count: The length of data to read
 *           Example: TYPE_0_LENGTH
 *  */
I2C_Mode I2C_Master_ReadReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t count);
void CopyArray(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest, uint8_t count);

bool i2c_write_byte(uint8_t byte);


I2C_Mode I2C_Master_ReadReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t count)
{
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;
    RXByteCtr = count;
    TXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB0I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB0IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts

    return MasterMode;

}


I2C_Mode I2C_Master_WriteReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count)
{
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;

    //Copy register data to TransmitBuffer
    CopyArray(reg_data, TransmitBuffer, count);

    TXByteCtr = count;
    RXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB0I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB0IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts

    return MasterMode;
}



void CopyArray(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest, uint8_t count)
{
    uint8_t copyIndex = 0;
    for (copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < count; copyIndex++)
    {
        dest[copyIndex] = source[copyIndex];
    }
}


//******************************************************************************
// Device Initialization *******************************************************
//******************************************************************************


void initGPIO()
{
    // Configure GPIO
    //LED_OUT &= ~(LED0_PIN | LED1_PIN); // P1 setup for LED & reset output
    //LED_DIR |= (LED0_PIN | LED1_PIN);

    // I2C pins
    P1OUT  |= BIT2 | BIT3;
    //P1REN  |= BIT2 | BIT3;
    P1SEL0 |= BIT2 | BIT3;
    P1SEL1 &= ~(BIT2 | BIT3);

    // I2C Level Shifter Enable
    P1OUT &= ~BIT1;                         // Clear P1.1 output latch for a defined power-on state
    P1DIR |= BIT1;                          // Set P1.1 to output direction
    P1OUT |= BIT1;                          // Turn on P1.1

    // 5V DCDC Converter Enable
    P2OUT &= ~BIT2;                         // Clear P2.2 output latch for a defined power-on state
    P2DIR |= BIT2;                          // Set P2.2 to output direction
    P2OUT |= BIT2;                          // Turn on P2.2

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
}

void initClockTo16MHz()
{
    // Configure one FRAM waitstate as required by the device datasheet for MCLK
    // operation beyond 8MHz _before_ configuring the clock system.
    FRCTL0 = FRCTLPW | NWAITS_1;

    // Clock System Setup
    __bis_SR_register(SCG0);                           // disable FLL
    CSCTL3 |= SELREF__REFOCLK;                         // Set REFO as FLL reference source
    CSCTL0 = 0;                                        // clear DCO and MOD registers
    CSCTL1 &= ~(DCORSEL_7);                            // Clear DCO frequency select bits first
    CSCTL1 |= DCORSEL_5;                               // Set DCO = 16MHz
    CSCTL2 = FLLD_0 + 487;                             // DCOCLKDIV = 16MHz
    __delay_cycles(3);
    __bic_SR_register(SCG0);                           // enable FLL
    while(CSCTL7 & (FLLUNLOCK0 | FLLUNLOCK1));         // FLL locked
}

void initI2C()
{
    UCB0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK | UCSYNC; // I2C master mode, SMCLK
    UCB0BRW = 160;                            // fSCL = SMCLK/160 = ~100kHz
    UCB0I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;                   // Slave Address
    UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE |= UCNACKIE;
}


//******************************************************************************
// Main ************************************************************************
// Send and receive three messages containing the example commands *************
//******************************************************************************

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    initClockTo16MHz();
    initGPIO();
    initI2C();

    //I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_0_MASTER, MasterType0, TYPE_0_LENGTH);
    //I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_1_MASTER, MasterType1, TYPE_1_LENGTH);

    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, Message1_Reg, Message1, TYPE_2_LENGTH);
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, Message2_Reg, Message2, TYPE_2_LENGTH);

    /*

    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_0_SLAVE, TYPE_0_LENGTH);
    CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType0, TYPE_0_LENGTH);

    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_1_SLAVE, TYPE_1_LENGTH);
    CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType1, TYPE_1_LENGTH);

    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_2_SLAVE, TYPE_2_LENGTH);
    CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType2, TYPE_2_LENGTH);

     */

    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);



    return 0;
}


//******************************************************************************
// I2C Interrupt ***************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_B0_VECTOR))) USCI_B0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  //Must read from UCB0RXBUF
  uint8_t rx_val = 0;
  switch(__even_in_range(UCB0IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
  {
    case USCI_NONE:          break;         // Vector 0: No interrupts
    case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;         // Vector 2: ALIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                // Vector 4: NACKIFG
      break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;         // Vector 6: STTIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;         // Vector 8: STPIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 10: RXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 12: TXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 14: RXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 16: TXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 18: RXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 20: TXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:                 // Vector 22: RXIFG0
        rx_val = UCB0RXBUF;
        if (RXByteCtr)
        {
          ReceiveBuffer[ReceiveIndex++] = rx_val;
          RXByteCtr--;
        }

        if (RXByteCtr == 1)
        {
          UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
        }
        else if (RXByteCtr == 0)
        {
          UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE;
          MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
          __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
        }
        break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                 // Vector 24: TXIFG0
        switch (MasterMode)
        {
          case TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE:
              UCB0TXBUF = TransmitRegAddr;
              if (RXByteCtr)
                  MasterMode = SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE;   // Need to start receiving now
              else
                  MasterMode = TX_DATA_MODE;        // Continue to transmision with the data in Transmit Buffer
              break;

          case SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE:
              UCB0IE |= UCRXIE;              // Enable RX interrupt
              UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE;             // Disable TX interrupt
              UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;            // Switch to receiver
              MasterMode = RX_DATA_MODE;    // State state is to receive data
              UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;          // Send repeated start
              if (RXByteCtr == 1)
              {
                  //Must send stop since this is the N-1 byte
                  while((UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTT));
                  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;      // Send stop condition
              }
              break;

          case TX_DATA_MODE:
              if (TXByteCtr)
              {
                  UCB0TXBUF = TransmitBuffer[TransmitIndex++];
                  TXByteCtr--;
              }
              else
              {
                  //Done with transmission
                  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;     // Send stop condition
                  MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
                  UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE;                       // disable TX interrupt
                  __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
              }
              break;

          default:
              __no_operation();
              break;
        }
        break;
    default: break;
  }
}
```

On the custom PCB I have a direct connection from the MSP430 via a TCA9406 I2C level shifter with integrated pull-ups to the PCA9955B. I measured on the side B of the level shifter.

[Schematic Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypDzl.png)

Best, Josh

Comment: Indeed, "SDA must not change between a rising edge of SCL and the subsequent falling edge": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Timing_diagram. Probably someone with MSP430 experience code see a problem with your setup of the controller. Give her a chance and show what code you use to initialize and control the I2C controller.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just uploaded my code.

Comment: The I²C communication looks OK (but the rising edges are suspiciously sharp; I guess you are using a TXS). Show a schematic, and tell us where you've measure the signals.

Comment: Well observed. I am using a level shifter for the I2C bus. I measured on the 5V side (side B) of the level shifter towards the LED driver. Uploaded the detail of the schematic. You said it looks OK but doesn't it look different from the TI document with regard to the phase between the signals?

Answer (score 0):

I found my stupid mistake. The PCA9955B requires an EXTERNAL pull-up resistor on its ~RESET pin.

[image: PCA9955B Pin Description]

I2C seems to be working fine.